# Cannot run javascript in yeoman generator-angular-fullstack?

Tags: javascript, css, generator, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman generator named generator-angular-fullstack. I added a responsive admin template into my project, but when the page load, javascript files doesn't run such as compents: tooltip, sidebar, ...
Thanks very much